# Source-path baseclass definition not found when compiling AS3 in mxmlc

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxmlc

As it's warmup time in Ludum Dare, I thought I'd make sure the Flex SDK I'd just downloaded works. Short answer: it doesn’t.

Every time I try to run

```
./mxmlc -compiler.source-path=../../../Flixel/org/flixel ../../../Flash/FindTheLight/src/FindTheLight.as
```

I get:

```
Config in /Users/jonatannoponen/Developer/Tools/flex_sdk_4.6/frameworks/flex-config.xml loading
/Users/jonatannoponen/Developer/Flash/FindTheLight/src/FindTheLight.as(7): sar.: 36 Error: Baseclass FlxGame definition not found.

public class FindTheLight extends FlxGame
                                  ^`
```

Comment: Flixel is a Flash Library independent of Flex.  It sounds like you didn't put the Flixel library in your library path: http://flixel.org/ .  This doesn't mean the Flex SDK doesn't work, though.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I tried putting flixel in `-source-path` and in `-library-path`, and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, SDK can't find the `FlxGame` class. Where does your `FlxGame.as` located? 
Also, don't you think that using an IDE (FlashDevelop, for example) can solve your problem? Just curious.

Comment: An IDE certainly makes the development easier; but It will still negate the need to add the external library to the library path; which is what I believe is the issue here.

Comment: I don't think the word "negate" means what you think it means, unless you mean that it *won't* negate the need.

Comment: My typo; that should have been "...it still won't negate the need..."

Comment: @amdc FlxGame.as is in `../../../Flixel/org/flixel`. FlashDevelop is Windows only, I have MacOS. I have used Flash Builder, but my trial expired.